# Counting keys in dictionary of dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, count

I have dict sample:

dictsample which have this structure `dictsample.update({key: dif_k})`, and dif_k have this structure `dif_k.update({k:v})`

dictsample:

```
{Object1 : { size : 14, cell: G, capacity : 35}, Object2 : { size : 14, load : 2}, Object3 : { size : 12, cell : F, load : 3, throughput : 55}, ...}
```

I need output like this:

```
{Object1 : 3, Object2 : 2, Object3 : 4, ...}
```

Code I have tried:

```
ct = {}
for key, dif_k in dictsample.iteritems():
    for k, v in dif_k.iteritems():
        dictcounter = k.count(k)
        ct.update({key:dictcounter})
```

And all I got is: 
    {Object1 : 1, Object2 : 1, Object3 : 1, ...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this:

```
the_list = {i:len(dictsample[i]) for i in dictsample.keys()}
```

this method does not require iteritems and is shorter.

Edit:

To access the values by a numerical element, try this:

```
the_list = {len(dictsample[i]):i for i in dictsample.keys()}
```

Comment: Thanks, but after that I have same problem with creating dataframe in pandas: 
If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
I commented above... what do I need to put as an index?  @Ajax1234

Comment: if you need a numerical index in the dictionary, just switch the dictionary key and values. Please see my recent edit.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this dict comprehension instead:

```
{k: len(v) for k,v in dictsample.iteritems()}
```

Comment: This works great, but I got a problem when trying to transform to dataframe:
If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
I wanna df with just first columns with keys and second with counted values.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you do it a bit simpler. Wouldn't something like this do the trick?

```
ct = {}
for key in dictsample:
    ct[key] = len(dictsample[key])
```

Comment: You don't need `dif_k.keys()`. Python already iterates over dictionaries by key by default. So `dif_k` is sufficient.

Comment: This works great too, as an answer above, but I got the same problem.